# What's the point in scouting low level players?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

In Xenoblade X's scout console I've been scouted by lots of players who are level 60, even though I'm only level 15. I can't understand why I would be scouted, surely that makes it more difficult for the level 60 scouting me?

Is there an advantage or reward gained from scouting people much lower than you when you get to that level? Or are people doing it just for the warm fuzzy feeling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They level your avatar up in exchange for BLADE medals, which they turn around and use to farm high level materials for better skells.